# SoundCloud API 401 error in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, soundcloud

I'm trying to get Soundcloud to return a track ID, but can't get it to work.  Documentation here (PHP tab): https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#errors

I've triple checked my credentials from soundcloud that I'm adding as args.

Function in my controller:

function formprocessor()
    {

```
    require_once (APPPATH.'third_party/Services/Soundcloud.php');

    // create a client object with your app credentials
    $client = new Services_Soundcloud('my client id', 'my client secret', 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.php/welcome/');


    try {
        $me = json_decode($client->get('me'), true);
    }
    catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
        exit($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

What would cause this to fail?  I keep getting a 401
Here's a reference to the API: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference

Answer (score 0):

you need to authenticate by sending the user (even if thats you) to "authorizeurl":

`$authURL = $client->getAuthorizeUrl();`

then set the access token with:

```
$accessToken = $client->accessToken($_GET['code']);
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);   //if you saved token in a session
```

Then you should at least be able to "get me" this part is working for me however i cannot access things such as /me/tracks/ or /me/followings/ at the moment.

Comment: Are you using Codeigniter for the example? $_GET vars are altered/disabled by default and not sure if this is the issue...  I still can't get this to work.

Comment: im just using php and the soundcloud api's. no third party software. not sure what codeigniters all about